# Getting SyntheticBaseEvent in console instead of item name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with my first react project. Right now I'm following a tutorial online to create a memory card game. When clicking the back of my card right now I'm getting this in the console:
`SyntheticBaseEvent` instead of the name of the card.
The only thing that I'm able to catch as possible error is that in my app function   `console.log(cards, turns)` is printed two times when I run my app and two times when I click "new game" and I don't think that's correct, but I have no idea on why this is happening.
This is my code:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import SingleCard from './components/SingleCard';

const cardImages = [
  {"src": "assets/img/helmet-1.png"},
  {"src": "assets/img/potion-1.png"},
  {"src": "assets/img/ring-1.png"},
  {"src": "assets/img/scroll-1.png"},
  {"src": "assets/img/shield-1.png"},
  {"src": "assets/img/sword-1.png"},
]

const App = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [turns, setTurns] = useState(0);
  const [choiceOne, setChoiceOne] = useState(null);
  const [choiceTwo, setChoiceTwo] = useState(null);

  // shuffle cards
  const shuffleCards =  () => {
    const shuffledCards = [...cardImages, ...cardImages]
    .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
    .map((card) => ({...card, id: Math.random()}))

    setCards(shuffledCards)
    setTurns(0)
  }

  console.log(cards, turns)

  // handle a choice 
  const handleChoice = (card) => {
    console.log(card)

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Magic Match</h1>
      <button onClick={shuffleCards}>New Game</button>
      <div className='card-grid'>
        {cards.map(card => (
          <SingleCard key={card.id} card={card} handleChoice={handleChoice} />

        ))}
      </div>

    </div>
  )

}


export default App
```

SingleCard.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './SingleCard.css'

const SingleCard = ({ card, handleChoice }) => {
    
    const handleClick = (card) =>{
        // console.log(card)
        handleChoice(card)

    }
  return (
    <div className='card'>
        <div>
        <img className='front' src={card.src} alt="card front" />
        <img className='back' src="assets/img/cover.png" onClick={handleClick} alt="card back" />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SingleCard
```

Comment: When you call `handleClick` on the `onClick` event of the card back, you are not passing the `card` object, which results in logging `SyntheticBaseEvent` instead of the card information.

Comment: Thanks I was able to fix thanks to your prompt! But I'm still not understanding why   `console.log(cards, turns)` it's printed two times, any suggestion?

Comment: This is expected since the App function component is re-rendered whenever its state is updated. The logs appear once on the initial render and again when you click the "New Game" button since `setCards` and `setTurns` update the state. If you want to log only on specific events, you can move the console.log inside the corresponding event handlers like `shuffleCards`